# Восстановить стили

Tags: javascript, jquery, style

Есть функция которая добавляет новые стили на указанный класс при нажатии на кнопку. Перед тем как добавить стили скрипт сначало ищет совпадения с `value` кнопки и `data-time` у `div`. Проблема заключается в следующем как при нажатии на другую кнопку с другим значением удалить стили, которые были применены в предыдущий раз?
Вот скрипт:

```
<script>
    var cats = document.querySelector(".categories"),
        click = function click(e) {
            var el = document.querySelectorAll(".fil0[data-time=\"" + e.target.value + "\"]");
            if (el) {
                $(el).css('fill', 'red');
            }
        };
    [].forEach.call(cats.children, function (e) {
        return e.addEventListener("click", click);
    });
</script>
```

Дивы:

```
<polygon class="fil0 str0" data-time="1" points="6584,19891 6584,23682 10061,23682 10061,19891 "/>
<polygon class="fil0 str0" data-time="2" points="6584,19891 6584,23682 10061,23682 10061,19891 "/>
<polygon class="fil0 str0" data-time="3" points="6584,19891 6584,23682 10061,23682 10061,19891 "/>
```

И кнопки:

```
<button type="button" value="1" class="category">1</button>
<button type="button" value="2" class="category">2</button>
<button type="button" value="3" class="category">3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Бросайте предыдущие изменяемые стили в отдельный массив (обновляя каждый раз при изменении, естественно), и запоминайте их значения(их можно получить стандартными методами js https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes), если просто изменяете параметры: например, было display:inline, а Вы, в теле функции изменили на display:block и inline, соответственно, нужно запомнить, а если добавляете, какие-то новые, то можно также получать значения( “none”) или пихать вручную. P.s.: Пример кода бросить сейчас не могу тк с телефона... но, по крайней мере, постарался изложить свою мысль

Comment: было бы круто если вы показали пример

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так: я добавялю класс `active`, но перед его добавляением я удаляю его у всех элементов крч вот скрипт:

```
var cats = document.querySelector(".categories"),
        click = function click(e) {
            var el = document.querySelectorAll(".fil0[data-time=\"" + e.target.value + "\"]");
            var fil = document.querySelectorAll(".fil0");
            if (el) {
                $(fil).removeClass("active");
                $(el).toggleClass("active");
            }
        };
    [].forEach.call(cats.children, function (e) {
        return e.addEventListener("click", click);
    });
```